# Handling selection and navigation in the same table view cell in iOS

Tags: usability, navigation, tables, ios, selection

I've a list of items in a table view, each of which display a small image and a name, as well as a disclosure indicator to navigate to a view with the item's details:

[image: table view]

The behavior I want is to be able to see a tapped item's details, and also be able to mark one of the items as selected (currently, checkmark at left side of the cell). When a cell is tapped, I display another view similar to this:

[image: details view -- the first row is expanded]

where a button to select the current item is placed, since I couldn`t use the tap gesture on the cell to both display the details view and mark the cell as selected.

However, this pattern forces the user to navigate to the details simply to select the item. I've been thinking about providing a control within the item's cell (in the first image) to select/deselect it when tapping such control, any ideas? A custom checkbox on the left side? A button? What may iOS users expect? I need this to conform the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

**EDIT:** In case I'd perform selection/deselection by means of an specific gesture for that, instead of adding a control within the cell, which gesture should it be? Touch and hold? Simple tap is already the standard touch for navigation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's own Reminders app has a good example of the functionality you are asking about.

Reminders has a left column of checkboxes next to the items and a disclosure chevron on the right side of the reminder column. Touching a checkbox selects the checkbox and touching the reminder slides the user to the details page.

Link to image: http://images.macworld.com/images/article/2011/06/reminders-todo-list-241582.png

Comment: Do you have a screen shot or mock up of this? If you can't post the image, just post the link, someone else can add it as a displayed image (I'm not sure if the image permissions for questions are the same as answers).

Comment: @wootcat thanks, I think a checkbox like those would be the best option... my first one was using switches as they are standard iOS SDK controls, but I think such controls are more appropiate for settings, aren`t they?

Comment: @AppsDev I believe so. The checkboxes should also take up less space than a switch. Seeing as that layout is used in an Apple-branded app, I would expect and hope it would be available somewhere and you wouldn't have to roll your own.

Comment: @wootcat And by setting a gesture for that? There is any example of, for instance, tapping and holding a cell for opening an editing view or something similar?

Comment: @AppsDev, From my recollection, there are very few examples of the tap+hold gesture. iOS uses it for activating the ability to move and delete apps, but I cannot think of an app I use which uses that gesture inside the app. In Reminders, you tap on the checkbox to check it (to the left of the vertical red line). Tapping anywhere to the right of the line slides the user to the details screen.

Comment: If the user taps on the Edit button on the upper right corner, the checkboxes are replaced with delete icons and the disclosure chevrons are replaced with the 3-horizontal line icon to reorder the list.

Comment: @wootcat thanks again. I found an example of the use of the tap and hold gesture in Calendar: tapping+holding a day in the month view, the new event modal view is displayed

Comment: @AppsDev - Ah! I was not aware of that functionality! So, the tap+hold does the same thing has selecting a date and pressing the + button at the top left of the screen. Based on that, I'm sure there must be more, but it seems there's no clear way to indicate that functionality.